# I cant make two separated text in single sticky div

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css, infact new to coding, however i am trying to  practice what i've learned by trying easy and small things. Where i'm stuck is, i am trying to add 2 separated texts into a single `<div>` which will be placed in left and right side. My purpose is to make them look like a menu by making them sticky with those 2 separated texts but the text on the right side is also a motto and when you click on it, for example will open `stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Welcome!  Everyone's first questions on this site usually gets downvoted.  Take posting questions here more seriously and considering waiting until you get more stabilized with your learning.  Questions do well when you show the code you have so far, tell your desired outcome, your current outcome and what you've tried so far.  The knowledge in the links above will be extremely useful to you.

Comment: i thank everyone who shows good intention. I have no problems with criticism as long as i know the reason within respectful borders. I have tried to copy my code in here but something somewhere went wrong and it didnt let me so when i deleted the code i was able to post my question. I will show the code next time when i have another problem but for now a little example is enough for me for it is not a hard code to write for experienced ones.

Comment: Ok.  I'll post a very basic example with what you want.  Just remember for next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's a overly basic example of what you can do.   I will update this with more detail if you update your question.*

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOKgvL

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.list-nav li{
  display: inline;
}
```